# Sync Phone Contacts with App

Tags: android, contacts, synchronization, android-syncadapter, contentobserver

I want to sync the phone contacts (name and phone number) with my contentProviver 'contacts' in my app. So I search and find two ways: ContentOberver and SyncAdapter.

In my case I don't need conection with Internt therefore I only sync with the database of my app. If the user delete a contact I want to delete in my database too, the same for update or insert.

So ContentObserver is the better way for this case?

There is a way to know the key of a contact? Like a key of a row in db. If yes I can update my db frequently (the user can choose the time).

Answer (score 0):

You need a sync adapter if you want to add contacts that are flagged as your application's contact.
If you don't add your sync adapter the contacts won't be shown. 
When you add the sync adapter you will also need an Authenticator. You can use a dummy authenticator that always add the same user without asking anything to the user.
Something you need to take into considerstion is that the sync adapter will never be triggered if there isn't an internet connection. For this reason you need to trigger the sync manually when something changes in your data.

To do something similar to what you described I developed a sync adapter a syncronizer that I also trigger directly and a ContentObserver to know when for example the user deletes a contact in the native addressbook.

If your sync is one way only that means that you don't need to insert/modify from your application you don't need a sync adapter.

Comment: In my app the user can select some contacs for block calls (like a white list) so I need only read contacts in my app. My database should have the same database of cellphone contacts so when the user change a name a contact automatically my app will change the name too.

Comment: I looked deeper ContentObserver and I think that don't work for my purpose because I have to inicialize it, but I can use alarm to inicialize periodically.

Comment: What do you think I have to do?

Comment: I used ContentObserver for doing things like that. I register the observer in the Application creation. When the application starts I run a sync. In my case there is no need to keep the application in-sync when it is not running. Since the synchronization takes time and you do not want to start it several times when for example the user imports several contacts, you need to deregister the ContentObserver while synching.

Comment: Yes there is a key: search for "lookup key for contacts"